# Pralaya at end of every Yuga cycle

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, pralaya

Many scripts talk about re-creation at the end of pralaya, and pralaya at the end of kalpa.

In this [section](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm#fr_46) for example, it is said that

> And when those terrible times will be over, the creation will begin anew.

which is saying after Kaliyuga, re-creation starts.

A kalpa is thousand Yuga cycles, which says, not end of every Kaliyuga ends in pralaya.

If so, how the texts say end of Kaliyuga resets the creation? If it is reset at end of kalpa then current Kaliyuga will not end in Pralaya?

Comment: This is not duplicate. The answer linked as duplicate is about what happens at end of Kaliyuga. My question is the differences of pralaya at end of Kaliyuga when mahayuga ends Vs at end of kalpa Vs at end of Brahma's life.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 types of Pralaya:

1. **Nitya** - people born and die everyday
2. **Naimittika** - after 1 kalpa (daytime) of Brahma (1000 chatur-yugas), 3 worlds, including earth are destroyed (whether 'destroyed' means complete destruction, or just submerged in water, not sure)
3. **Prakrita** - after 1 lifetime of Brahma, entire 14 worlds dissolved into Prakriti (other Andas ruled by other Brahmas might stay on)
4. **Atyantika** - soul gets Moksha

At end of Kali Yuga, only people/species get reset. Currently were in 28th Chatur-Yuga. Kali duration is 4,32,000 years. Of which we are currently in year 5121/22. When it ends, Krita Yuga of 29th Chatur-Yuga will restart.

Comment: You can add scriptural ref..I think the above can be found in initial chapters of Vishnu Purana..

Comment: @ram So, at end of Kaliyuga, **all** people/species in earth are reset but earth remains? And, if so (if clean reset) how the rishis from Ramayana period remained for Mahabharata...both happened in differences chaturyugas. Or, is it reset of the evil only...which will be an extension of Nitya but not as strong as Naimittika?

Comment: @SHebbar You r right.. Yugantaka and Manvantarantaka pralya would be extension of Nitya but not as strong as Naimittika..for example, the great flood before the current manvantara or Mahabharata war are extentions of Nitya pralaya..

Comment: @SHebbar - only bad guys are killed at end of Kali by Kalki avatar. Good people will still remain, and their progeny will likely populate Krita Yuga.

Comment: How do you know Kali Yuga is at the end of the cycle?